# How do I get a variable from a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I  have a for each loop iterating through cart content. I want to fetch the `shop_id` anduse it in another query.

```
    $cartcontents = Cart::content()->toArray();
    foreach ($cartcontents as $cartcontent) {
            $shop_id = DB::table('products')->where('id', $cartcontent['id'])->value('shop_id');
            break;        
    } 
    $shop_number = DB::table('shops')->where('id',$shop_id)->value('phone_number');
    echo $shop_number;
```

I am getting an error `Undefined variable: shop_id`. I don't know why yet the same code works in another section of the function.

Comment: I think you don't need to use foreach, because you only need to take the data from your first item in the array $cartcontents.

Comment: why do you have a `break` in your foreach? does it mean that you can have multiple items but is it just coming from one store? but anyways, just initialise a variable before the foreach

Comment: @Kevin The cart content can have more than one item and the arrays are different for each cart

Answer (score 0):

Your shop_id variable is out of scope. Your query line cannot access value of shop_id because the shop id was declared inside foreach which is different scope. To fix the issue, declare the shop_id above foreach to match the scope.

```
 $shop_id = null; 
 $cartcontents = Cart::content()->toArray();
    foreach ($cartcontents as $cartcontent) {
            $shop_id = DB::table('products')->where('id', $cartcontent['id'])->value('shop_id');
            break;        
    } 
    $shop_number = DB::table('shops')->where('id',$shop_id)->value('phone_number');
    echo $shop_number;
```